Map between Weyl modules in terms of Young tableaux
The irreducible algebraic representations of $\text{GL}_n$ over the complex numbers are given by highest weight representations of dominant weights $\lambda=(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n): k_1 \ge k_2 \ge \ldots \ge k_n$. Let me only consider the ones that satisfy $k_n \ge 0$. Then a basis of the highest weight representation $V_{\lambda}$ is given by semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$. Let $T$ be such a tableau, writing its entries $(a_{ij})$ in matrix form. Define $T_{ij}$ as the tableau obtained by replacing $a_{ij}$ by $1$.
The $T_{ij}$ will in general be non-standard tableaux, which one can write as linear combinations of standard ones.
Consider the following map of vector spaces (not as representations)
$
\phi: V_{\lambda} \to V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{(1,0,\ldots,0)} \to V_{\lambda+(1,0,\ldots,0)}
$
given by sending a tableau $T$ to $\sum_{i,j} T_{ij} \otimes [1]$, with $[1]$ the unique tableau of shape $(1,0,\dots,0)$ with entry $1$.
Question: is $\phi$ always injective?
Apologies if this can be easily solved using the literature, I work in an area far away from this question.

A basis is given by semistandard tableaux, not standard.

How do you define your embedding $V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{(1)} \to V_{\lambda + (1)}$ ? You add a box in the first row with content 1?

@eti902 Yes. Let $(i)$ be a basis element of $V_(1)$, with $i=1,\ldots,n$. Then $T^{\lambda} \otimes (i)$ is sent to the tableau where you adjoin $(i)$ to the first row of $T^{\lambda}$. You will have to rearrange the first row, but there is a unique way to do this.
